# Angular2-ui-switch Giving an error

Tags: angular

I've been trying to load angular2-ui-switch into my application .but i've been getting an error as follows:

```
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/angular2-ui-switch
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/angular2-ui-switch as "angular2-ui-switch" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
(anonymous) @ ?buIds=fidelity-BlrEGL,demo-ETS:33
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232
Zone.run @ zone.js:114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:502
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:339
```

I have follwed all the instructions given in the readme.
The link to the module is : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-ui-switch

my systemjs.config.js is :

```
    /**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'moment': 'npm:moment' ,
      app: 'app',
      'mydatepicker': 'npm:mydatepicker',
       'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/src/multiselect-dropdown':'npm:angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/src/multiselect-dropdown',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
      'angular2-google-maps': 'npm:angular2-google-maps',

    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-google-maps':{
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      mydatepicker: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }, 
      'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/src/multiselect-dropdown':{
        main:'../multiselect-dropdown',
        defaultExtension:'js'
      },    
      'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
      'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js',
      moment: { main: './moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    }
  });
})(this);
```

What am i doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't add the module to your systemjs.config.js I guess

Add this in the map:

```
'angular2-ui-switch': 'npm:angular2-ui-switch'
```

And in packages:

```
'angular2-ui-switch': {
    main: 'node_modules/angular2-ui-swith-main-class-to-find'
    defaultExtension: 'js',
}
```

Comment: Oh okay ! Thank you :) . I kinda understood what the error meant and what i had to do . But never knew how to add the module to systmejs.config.js. : )